# errno location on different systems

Tags: c++, c, std, errno

I have confusions about what implementation of errno() should I use in my programs.

As far as I know, the standard errno() is defined in errno.h. However, Visual Studio also has errno() in stdlib.h. Maybe that's incorrect, but for me stdlib.h's errno() is faster than errno.h's one. But errno() is also defined in stddef.h.

Which one should I use? `#ifdef _WIN32 #include <stdlib.h> #else #include <errno.h> #endif`?

Comment: What does `errno()` mean? Are you trying to invoke `errno` like a function?

Comment: Rob, I wrote parentheses to avoid confusion between `errno` symbol and `errno.h` file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C, use `errno.h` and in C++ use `cerrno` header.

`errno` can be defined in other headers for convenience but for maximum portability you should use the ones above.

Comment: Okay, but what's fastest implementation on different systems?

Comment: @SiPlus : How should we know? Measure it and tell us. ;-]

Comment: `errno` cannot be defined in other headers; any implementation that does so is wrong and broken.

Comment: @R.. the C Standard does not let as is it does for `NULL` for example but it is the case in some implementations. Same for standard headers, they cannot include any other standard headers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Windows, but on Linux/Unix, `errno` is defined in `errno.h` .